# Interpret the output of a GLMM with binomial data

Tags: glmm

I am a biology student looking at the occurrence of a certain behaviour during breeding in an animal and which variables predict the occurrence of that behaviour.
The behaviour was recorded as "yes" or "no"
After building up the model and looking at the output (down below) the variable Oestrus seems to be the only significant one. Oestrus was also recorded as "yes" or "no".

Question:
Since Oestrus predicts the occurrence of my behaviour how do I read (in the output) which of the levels of it predicts the occurrence of the behaviour I am looking at. When Oestrus is 0 AggYN is 1? Or the other way around?

Bonus question:
With only 4 fixed effects, does it make sense to do backwards selection to my model?

Thank you!

## The Model

`modelaggYN = glmer(AggYN ~ Age + SocialF + SocialM + Oestrus + (1|Zoo) + (1|MID) + (1|FID), data=Data_Ok, family= "binomial")`

## The output

````
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: AggYN ~ Age + SocialF + SocialM + Oestrus + (1 | Zoo) + (1 |      MID) + (1 | FID)
   Data: Data_Ok

    AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    80.0     98.6    -32.0     64.0       67 

Scaled residuals: 
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.059526 -0.000009  0.000000  0.002122  0.078902 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 FID    (Intercept) 2350.86  48.486  
 MID    (Intercept) 7044.59  83.932  
 Zoo    (Intercept)   74.41   8.626  
Number of obs: 75, groups:  FID, 40; MID, 39; Zoo, 21

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -37.7317    14.8321  -2.544   0.0110 *
Age          -0.1983     0.4004  -0.495   0.6205  
SocialF1     14.4633     7.6771   1.884   0.0596 .
SocialM1      5.3020     6.0449   0.877   0.3804  
Oestrus     -18.8992     8.3612  -2.260   0.0238 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) Age    SoclF1 SoclM1
Age      -0.177                     
SocialF1 -0.916  0.262              
SocialM1 -0.460  0.313  0.342       
Oestrus   0.887 -0.184 -0.848 -0.344
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0525962 (tol = 0.002, component 1)```
````

Comment: since the coefficient for oestrus is negative, it is indeed correct that it when it is 0 AggYN is more likely to be 1. Regarding your bonus question, I would say: backwards selection is not necessary when there are only 2^4=16 possible models. You might try a model with only Oestrus and SocialF1 and see if that pushes your SocialF1 p-value below the 0.05 threshold (and of course comment clearly in your eventual manuscript that that was a post-hoc analysis).

Comment: Thank you very much John for your help!